# Why I can't use the same argument to show that $\overline{B} = \cup_{i=0}^\infty \overline{A_i}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm solving the following problem from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (chapter 2):

---

*Let $A_1, A_2, A_3,...$ be subsets of a metric space*

*(a) If $B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ prove that $\overline{B_n} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$*

*(b) If $B = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ prove that $\overline{B} \supset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{A_i}$. Show by an example that this inclusion can be proper*

---

**My attempt:**

For (a):

Let $\epsilon >0 $ then:

$x \in \overline{B_n}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i}$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $B(x,\epsilon) \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \neq \varnothing$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $B(x,\epsilon) \cap A_j \neq \varnothing$ (for some $j \in \{ 1,...,n\}$)

$\Leftrightarrow x \in \overline{A_j}$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$

So $\overline{B_n} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$

For (b) I have thought of an example where the inclusion is proper, but I don't understand why I can't apply the same argument as in (a). I know that working with an infinite collection of things is different from working with a finite collection, but for this case I think the argument I used for (a) could work even for an infinite collection of subsets so that $\overline{B} = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{A_i}$ (which is not true)

My intuition is that the $j$ I used for (a) might depend on $\epsilon$ and might not be well defined if the collection of subsets is infinite. Is that true? Or is there another (perhaps more detailed) reason why I can't repeat the argument of (a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is formally slightly wrong: in the second equivalence, the condition should hold **for all** $\epsilon>0$. Also, the missing crucial step is the fact that in order to conclude that $x\in \overline{A_i}$ for some $i$, then you need to show (once again) that $B(x,\epsilon)\cap A_i\neq\emptyset$ **for all** $\epsilon>0$. This is the part that fails for the case of infinite unions.

As a counterexample, you can consider eg the sequence of singletons $A_i=\{\frac{1}{i}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.